# Error for enumerable when using JsonConvert.SerializeObject

Tags: c#, json.net, ienumerable

I am getting error, when i try to convert object into json using json.net.

Error:

```
  Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]' to type
 'MyNamespace.Domain.Entity'.
```

Class to be serialized:

```
[Serializable]
public class Business:Entity
    {
        public virtual string TemplateName { get; set; }

        public virtual CalculationBasis CalculationBasis { get; set; }

        public virtual PeriodSelectionType PeriodSelectionType { get; set; }

        public virtual DateTime PeriodEndDate { get; set; }

        public virtual IEnumerable<int> mainKeys { get; set; }
  }
```

Serialization Code:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
    settings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat;
    var strJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( ObjectOfBusiness, settings);
```

Deserialization Code:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Business>(ObjectOfBusiness, settings);
```

I am only getting this error, when i have values in `IEnumerable<int> mainKeys`

NOTE: mainKeys is a `List<int>`

Looks like error is because of its parent class "Entity" , the class is like this:

```
  [Serializable]
    public abstract class Entity
    {
        public Entity()
        {
        }

        public Entity(int id)
        {
            this.Id = id;
        }

        public virtual int Id { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            Entity other = (Entity)obj;
            return this.Id == other.Id;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return this.Id.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Don't know why json.net is trying to convert IEnumerable into "entity" type (its parent class)..

I can't remove entity (parent class) as its been used from lots of places..

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: well, what was `ObjectOfBusiness` in the two locations ? was it an instance of `Business`? (kinda need to check that...): and what is the value of `strJson`?

Comment: Ah, I guess the issue is `mainKeys`... what value did that have?

Comment: @Marc: ObjectOFBusiness is object of business class (which is needed to serialize), and mainKeys is IEnumerable of Int so, it contains integer values..

Comment: "IEnumerable of Int" simply tells me *what it can do* - it doesn't tell me *what it is*. What it *is* is something like "it is a vector of int (`int[]`)", "it is a `List<int>`", "it is an iterator block (`yield return`)", or "it is some custom class I created that implements `IEnumerable<int>`"

Comment: its list of int.. List<int>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the solution.
the issue is because of poor code in `override bool Equals(object obj)` method.
The correct code is:

```
  public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is Entity)
            {
                Entity other = (Entity) obj;
                return this.Id == other.Id;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

http://json.codeplex.com/workitem/16554

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer - it is a "this works fine":

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class Entity { }
public class CalculationBasis { }
public class PeriodSelectionType { }
[Serializable]
public class Business : Entity
{
    public virtual string TemplateName { get; set; }
    public virtual CalculationBasis CalculationBasis { get; set; }
    public virtual PeriodSelectionType PeriodSelectionType { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime PeriodEndDate { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<int> mainKeys { get; set; }
}
class program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
        settings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat;

        var ObjectOfBusiness = new Business
        {
            TemplateName = "abc",
            CalculationBasis = new CalculationBasis(),
            PeriodSelectionType = new PeriodSelectionType(),
            PeriodEndDate = new DateTime(),
            mainKeys = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
        };
        var strJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ObjectOfBusiness, settings);
        //...
        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Business>(strJson, settings);
        // ^^^^ all good
    }
}
```

So: it would be really good if you could show a *failing* case, or give us more clues to go on. For info, the JSON in the above is:

```
{"TemplateName":"abc","CalculationBasis":{},"PeriodSelectionType":{},"PeriodEndDate":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","mainKeys":[1,2,3,4,5]}
```

Comment: thanks Marc, I think i have written exactly same code except mainKeys, for me it a List of int List<int> .. and my code is failing because of that only..

Comment: if i convert List<int> to array then also getting similar error :Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32[]' to type 'MyDomain.Domain.Entity'.

Comment: @RajeshRolen-DotNetDeveloper again, it works for me for both `int[]` and `List<int>`. I can't make it fail. So I suspect the "fail" is in something *you aren't showing us*. Can you reproduce the error in a minimal example, like I have?

Comment: got the minimal error :)  the issue is because of its (business class) parent class "Entity", don't know why but its trying to cast that Ienumerable to entity (parent class) type..

Comment: if you will add entity class in your code, you will see the same error i am getting.... please suggest..